# C++ Add+Edit Text in Qt System() via Variables

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, system

I am new to C++ and my Problem is to Edit this function

```
 system("gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'cd ;cd catkin_ws/src/motoman/motoman_driver/src; ./move_to_joint.py [0,0,0.1,0,0,0];exit;exec bash'");
```

I would like to edit via variable how can i do that?

```
char test;

 system("gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'cd ;cd catkin_ws/src/motoman/motoman_driver/src; ./move_to_joint.py [%c,0,0.1,0,0,0];exit;exec bash'", test);
```

This doesn't work, how can I achieve this?

Comment: You do know that you can append `std::string` objects to each other using simple `+`? And you can also concatenate `std::string` object with single `char` values?

Comment: i would like to change these values [0,0,0,0,0,0] to some other values if i click a button. So it is [0.1,0,0,0,0,0] and the next time [0.2,0,0,0,0,0]